# input type text value not visible in safari ipad

Tags: ipad, input, safari

I have an input type text in an iframe. When I try to add value through document.getElementById('someid').value , it does not show the value in the text box. Strangely if I query it using either jquery or document.getElementById('someid').value, it fetches me the value. Also, when I type the value through keypad, it shows the value in it but strangely I cannot set it through javascript. Why can't I see the value in the input type text field? Any thoughts? I am not able to get any support from the web yet. Please help

Comment: I fixed this. There were duplicate IDs on the dom and hence value setting was not working on safari but was working in all other browsers

Answer (score 6):

it could be that this CSS causes the issue:
        * {
            -webkit-user-select: none;
        }

And avoid using focus();//jquery property

can you please try to remove it and give it a try?

Comment: The author of this question posted a comment to their own question stating that he fixed it already.

Comment: in my case the problem was sovled by doing above changes so i posted it may help others

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, add that into your answer +1